# Pandas, select dates using input from list

Tags: python, pandas

here is my input df:

```
df:
date , name
1990-12-21, adam1
1990-12-22, adam2
1990-12-23, adam3
1990-12-24, adam4
1990-12-25, adam5
```

I want to select all dates above given date from list (always on fist place)

```
list = ['1990-12-23','name','22']

df = pd.to_datetime(df['date'))

df = df[df.date > list[0]]
```

And its working.

My question is, why its working without converting this first element of a list to datetime format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas has flexible [Partial String Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing). This allows dates and times that can be automatically parsed into a `datetime` or `timestamp` to be used as strings without first converting them.

Comment: Yes that format will also work. But in general because there can be some confusion between the order of dates and months (i.e. '1990/03/05') I find it safer to always convert to a datetime first with the format specified.

Comment: thanks, it means that , if string looks same as dates in DF , its treated as datetime?, if it would look like : 1990/02/23 , it will not?

I mean if pandas can "cut" to selected date in string format, what happnd when dates will not be sorted?

Comment: one more question, when i am converting my elemnt from list to datetime in pandas i am receiving this error:
`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'`

and olso for previous solution, do pandas know when i am using string, to sort those dates?